# How to get list of current date data from mysql using hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

```
public <E> List viewc(String a,String c) {      
        List l1=new ArrayList();
        try {
            con = utilimpl.openSession();
            if(con != null)
            {
              st =  con.beginTransaction();
               Query q=con.createQuery("FROM "+a+"  WHERE cdate="+c+"");
                l1=q.list();
               st.commit();
              }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("no connection found!!");
            }

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(st != null)
            { 
                st.rollback();
            }
        }
        return l1;

        }
```

Below code is doget method code of servlet.i want to get list of data.cdate is column of my database and datatype is timestamp in mysql.

```
   SimpleDateFormat k=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date s=new Date();
    String c=k.format(s);       
    List<userModel> ln=d.viewc("userModel",c);
    request.setAttribute("list",ln);
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? Is there any error or it does not return any data? By the way, you have given method definition for "viewc" method, while your code states "d.getDatav("userModel",c);"

Comment: it does not return list of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since cdate is of timestamp type, it consists of date + time and you are trying to compare over date part only with equality.

Try something like this:

```
Query q=con.createQuery("FROM "+a+"  WHERE DATE(cdate)=DATE("+c+")");
```

**EDIT:** In order for the comparison to work, value of c and cdate should be in same format. In order to achieve this, query can be modified as follow:

```
Query q=con.createQuery("FROM "+a+"  WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE(cdate),'%Y-%m-%d')="+c);
```

Here c should be in format : 'yyyy-mm-dd', eg '2019-01-19'

DATE_FORMAT would convert the resulted date into the desired format as string value, and now comparison with 'c' should hold good.

Comment: please tell me how to get cdate from timestamp store in mysql DB

Comment: @PatelParth Please have a look at my updated answer. If it does not work, please share the SQL query that actually got executed.